# What does the middle button in Swarm Simulator do?

Tags: swarm-simulator

As in the question, what does this button do?

[image: Circled button]

I know the first one is one unit, the last is max, but I'm not sure of the middle.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is one exception to the 25% rule...

The exception is in the case of *Upgrades*.

For all upgrades, the middle button (if it appears) buys some larger fraction and the appearance of the middle option is intermittent and slightly buggy.

Often, this number is one less than the max amount, as here on the Meat tab:

[image: Meat tab 1-4-5]

And on the Larva tab:

[image: Expansion purchase 1-5-6]

After waiting the minute and a half for this to increment to "Buy 7", you can see that the middle option is still "Buy 5".

[image: Expansion purchase 1-5-7]

But if I go away for a little bit and come back, it's up at "Buy 6".

[image: Expansion purchase 1-6-7]

On the Territory tab you don't seem to get middle buttons for upgrades, though I think I've seen them in the past:

[image: Territory Purchase 1-19]

Upgrades on the Meat tab also occasionally don't get the middle button, though as shown in the first image, they sometimes *do*:

[image: Queens no middle button]

Edit: Got it to increment up and it added the middle button... like I said at the top, it's a bit buggy.

[image: Queens with middle button]

Answer (score 1):

It allows you to hatch 25% of your hive queens.

Answer (score 1):

In addition to Ealhad's answer, the middle button is always producing/obtaining 25% of the maximum producible item. It is only available when you can make at least 4 (iirc) of the wanted thing.